# File, Folder Observers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my app I have a folder named "constants" this holds all the constants for my app, from route names to image paths to font paths.

Now when I add an image to my images folder I need to manually add the constant to that file so it can be used anywhere in my app.  What I want is a way to "watch" or "observe" the images folder. So that whenever a new file is added it automatically modifies my constants/images.dart file and appends the new constant to that file.

Also want to do the same with routes, I have a screens folder so whenever a new screen is created a corresponding route constant should be created in constants/routes.dart.

I would like to know how I can achieve this in vs code.

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be part of your IDE but not part of your build script? or just a simple script file that watch the specific folder?

Comment: I dunno how to do it either way.  The fact is if any image is dropped into image folder I should immediately be able to reference the constant from code without having to build my app first.

Comment: What's the of your project? I can help with npm based (node, browser etc.) projects..

Comment: You can do this with an extension obviously but if you need it only for a one project is over killing (because it will run and slows all of your projects)

Comment: So my project is a dart project and I will use this as default for all my dart projects.

Comment: Can't help you with that.. Anyway, you can create an extension which [watch on file system changes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#details-1734) and when an image added, you can [modify](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#details-1753) the constants file according the images files names. Are you familiar with node / vscode extension api?

Comment: No I am not but will look into it.

Comment: Notify me if you have questions